# Getting CodeIgniter Active Record's current SQL code

Tags: php, activerecord, codeigniter

for example, i want to convert this;

```
$this->db->get('table');
```

to this;

```
'SELECT * FROM table'
```

is there any function for this? i searched on the user guide of CI but didnt find any solution.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can also use `$this->db->get_compiled_select()`. The difference between `get_compiled_select()` and `last_query()` is that `get_compiled_select()` gives the query string generated even if you don't run the query against the database.

Comment: I just realized that if you use `_compile_select()`, that you have to use `$this->db->_reset_select();` after executing the query.  If you don't, CodeIgniter won't clear the query, and all queries onward won't work.

Comment: `_compile_select()` is not working anymore because they protected the function at the latest CI2 Github repo. I used this function so many times and now I'm stuck. Maybe there is a solution?

Comment: After searching CI commit history, I just saw that there is a new public method; `get_compiled_select()`. http://codeigniter.com/nightly_user_guide/database/active_record.html#this-db-get-compiled-select

Comment: `get_compiled_select()` will be available with codeigniter-3 http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::get_compiled_select()

Answer (score 32):

Try

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

after you run your Active Record Query and it'll spit out the raw SQL it ran for you. I use it often.